# Cannot find name 'Queue'.ts(2304) in Typescript

Tags: typescript, npm

I am creating a private variable that is of the internal type `InnerItem`. But I keep getting the error

> Error: Cannot find name 'Queue'.ts(2304)

`private savedItems: Queue<InnerItem> = new Queue<InnerItem>(20);`

Is the syntax wrong or something else? I can't seem to pin point.

Comment: Have you created or imported a `Queue` class somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I installed through `npm install --save-dev queue-typescript` and then `import { Queue } from "queue-typescript"; `.  I just removed the `mode_modules` and reinstalled it. The error is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `node_modules` do get corrupted. Deleting and re-installing it removed the error. However, the steps were,

- Install `Queue` (I did `npm install --save-dev queue-typescript`)
- Import it correctly (`import { Queue } from "queue-typescript";`)
- Remove `node_modules` if the error is still there
- Re-install (`npm install`)

The error should be removed.